# master div not expanding with inner div

Tags: css

Doing some css, so threw this quick fiddle together to show the issue I am having.

http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/LJKsA/

The div block in center of the demo, is overlapping the container div.

Can you suggest a fix for this please, it always trips me up.

The center div can be larger as content is added, so outer div container needs to handle this also, and retain margins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `clear: both` to the last element inside the containing div.

Comment: hm... almost overlooked this correct answer because of the lack of code... maybe add a style rule in a code block... or something? :P

Answer (score 0):

This is asked 10 times a day on StackOverflow. It's because you're using `float` ont he children of the container div. Just impleemnt `overflow:hidden` to it and it should work.

Search more about clearfix, also.

Comment: Seriously. That's a "clearfix". It's better than the `clear:both` element.